# How to unset http.proxy in android

Tags: android, proxy

We can set system proxy by

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port);
```

How do you unset system proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `clearProperty`

```
System.clearProperty("http.proxyHost");
```